Mapbox how update style source
How to update the source style in mapbox, now I do it by first removing the layers, then the source and adding it again, but with a larger number of geojsons you can clearly see that the my "update" disappears and reappears after a while.
Below is the code so far:
Value geoJsonSourceValue = Value.fromJson(sourceJson.toString()).getValue();

mapView.getMapboxMap().removeStyleLayer("fill-layer");
mapView.getMapboxMap().removeStyleSource("c-source");

mapView.getMapboxMap().addStyleSource("c-source", geoJsonSourceValue);


String layerFillJson = "{"
+ "\"id\": \"fill-layer\","
+ "\"type\": \"fill\","
+ "\"source\": \"c-source\","
+ "}";

Value layerFillValue = Value.fromJson(layerFillJson).getValue();


mapView.getMapboxMap().addStyleLayer(layerFillValue, null);



